# Problem creating FeatureLayer object in esri javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer

I'm just a simple farmer tending to his ArcGIS online hosted feature layers.  I pinpointed the problem as that I can't seem to properly create a FeatureLayer object based on a url to a hosted feature layer.  I can execute query tasks and what not just fine, but I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong with creating a feature layer.  I tried just using an esri example feature layer, and it's still not working for me.  Am I just missing something dumb?  Javascript API v3.31 btw

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>testfeatures</title>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/"></script>
    <script>
      require([
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
    ], function(declare, dom, parser, ready, FeatureLayer) {
        parser.parse();

        ready(function() {
            var testLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/0", {
                mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_AUTO,
                outFields: ["*"]
            });

            console.log(testLayer);
            console.log(testLayer.fields)
        })
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Console logging the fields gives "undefined", whereas logging the feature layer itself gives me an object.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry you are doing OK, it's just that the layer has not load completely, check this example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>FeatureLayer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/"></script>
<style>
html, body, #map {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script>
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer
  ) {
    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [-82.44109, 35.6122],
      zoom: 6
    });
    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(
      "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/0",
      {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_AUTO,
        outFields: ["*"]
      }
    );
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(featureLayer.fields);
    }, 1000);
    console.log(featureLayer);
    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There you will see the result of `featureLayer.fields`.

Also, there was a similar old question about this [GIS SE - featureLayer.fields is undefined](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45533/featurelayer-fields-is-undefined)

Comment: I see! Alright, that makes total sense, I just hadn't though about the feature layer itself not loading yet.  Hadn't come across the older post.  Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps you!